# Call stored procedure in Django

Tags: django, stored-procedures, django-views

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Django that returns some data based on which batch number you give it. In my database if I write

```
call InkItUp.InkBatchNumberCallBackk(15137);
```

I return the data I need. But then I try to use Postman to call the URL I have defined for the view saveInkbatch in my urls.py file It gives me this error:

```
The view api.views.saveInkbatch didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Me urls.py look something like this:

```
path('createsp/', views.saveInkbatch),
```

and there is the method in the view.py

```html
@csrf_exempt
def saveInkbatch(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('batchnumber'):
                save=Ink()
                save.batchnumber=request.POST.get('batchnumber')
                cursor=connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("call InkItUp.InkBatchNumberCallBackk('"+save.batchnumber+"')")
                messages.success(request, "The batchnumber "+save.batchnumber+"")
                return HttpResponse(request, content_type = 'application/json')
```

[image]

If you know a way to call a stored procedure from MySQl with a class-based view - It would be nice to. I would much rather use class-based views if possibly.

Comment: Your view wants a POST, but your request was GET **Request Method: GET**.

Comment: but how do I tell it it is a post. if u see my URL I call the function and I only contains that view function